# set the scroll position of a "overflow-y element"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code

```
    <div style="width: 400px; height:200px; background-color: #090; overflow-y: scroll">
        <p>first</p>
        <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>last</p>
    </div>
```

I need at onclick some element, scroll bottom (maximal bottom) automatically, that is at onclick  some element, need this result:  [please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPwn4.jpg)

tell please how can make this?

Comment: default result from my code is scroll top for div  element, I need for example onclick on document, obtain scroll down for div element (see please screenshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<p id="last">last</p>` and `<a href="#last">Go to #last</a>`:

```
<div style="width: 400px; height:200px; background-color: #090; overflow-y: scroll">
    <p>first - <a href="#last">Go to #last</a></p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p id="last">last</p>
</div>
```

[​http://jsfiddle.net/bzuPy/](http://jsfiddle.net/bzuPy/)

Comment: Thanks, and if need after document onload obtain same result, what must be make?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you need to set it with Javascript, you can `location.href = "#last";` http://jsfiddle.net/bzuPy/1/